# Firebase storage security rules: Is it possible to use firebase database collection fields value in security rules? If not how can I solve this issue?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have migrated data to firebase storage, which have structure like:

```
<fileId>/<filename>
```

I can store fileIds associated with user in firebase database like:

```
<userId>/<fileids>
```

Is there anyway I can get something like `auth.uid/fileids` from firebase database in security rules of firestorage, to only allow to read file to auth user, if fileIds belong to him. If not, what all options are available to achieve the same and which one is best among them?

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible to use data from databases in your Cloud Storage security rules.  You can only use information about the object stored in the bucket.

You could instead write a backend API that performs all the checks and then operates on the object in storage, or store information about the file in its metadata for use in rules.